# Necesito ayuda urgente con modelo ER

Tags: base-de-datos

Pues se me hace muy difícil crear modelos entidad-relación y ya he hecho muchos ejercicios.

El problema es que un simple cambio en un párrafo del enunciado ya puede cambiar completamente el ejercicio. Por ejemplo en matemáticas, una ecuación de segundo grado tiene su fórmula y aunque te den unos valores u otros, la fórmula es la misma y su realización se basa en el seguimiento de las reglas.

Pero un modelo ER es mucho más abstracto. Solo quiero que me den unos pasos a seguir para que me resulte más sencillo hacerlo. (por ejemplo: primero haz todos las entidades y luego las relaciones y luego atributos /o ejemplo: ve añadiendo los modelos y entidades según sigas el enunciado).

Estoy desesperado ya, puesto que tengo un examen definitivo de ER pronto y no me veo en condiciones de aprobar aunque practique mucho.

Les dejo un ejemplo de un enunciado que me cayó en un ejercicio tipo examen.

**Ejercicio 2: Energía Eléctrica.**

> Se pretende llevar a cabo un control sobre la energía eléctrica que se produce y consume en un determinado país.
>
> Se parte de las siguientes hipótesis.
>
> Existen productores básicos de electricidad que se identifican por un nombre, de los cuales interesa su producción media, producción máxima y fecha de entrada en funcionamiento. Estos productores básicos pertenecen a algunas de las siguientes categorías: Central Hidroeléctrica, Central Solar, Central Nuclear o Central Térmica. De una central hidroeléctrica o presa interesa saber su ocupación, capacidad máxima y número de turbinas. De una central solar interesa saber la superficie total de paneles solares, la media anual de horas de sol y el tipo (fotovoltaica o termodinámica). De una central nuclear, interesa saber el número de reactores que posee, el volumen de plutonio consumido y el de residuos nucleares que produce. De una central térmica, interesa saber el número de hornos que posee, el volumen de carbón consumido y el volumen de su emisión de gases.
>
> Por motivos de seguridad nacional interesa controlar el plutonio de que se provee una central nuclear. Este control se refiere a la cantidad de plutonio que compra a cada uno de sus posibles suministradores (nombre y país) y que porta un determinado transportista (nombre y matrícula). Ha de tenerse en cuenta que un mismo suministrador puede vender plutonio a distintas centrales nucleares y que cada porte (un único porte por compra) puede realizarlo un transportista diferente.
>
> Cada día, los productores entregan la energía producida a una o varias estaciones primarias, las cuales pueden recibir diariamente una cantidad distinta de energía de cada uno de esos productores. Los productores entregan siempre el total de su producción. Las estaciones primarias se identifican por su nombre y tienen un número de transformadores de baja a alta tensión y son cabecera de una o varias redes de distribución.
>
> Una red de distribución se identifica por un número de red y sólo puede tener una estación primaria como cabecera. La propiedad de una red puede ser compartida por varias compañías eléctricas. A cada compañía eléctrica se le identifica por su nombre. La energía sobrante en una de las redes puede enviarse a otra red. Se registra el volumen total de energía intercambiada entre dos redes.
>
> Una red está compuesta por una serie de líneas, cada línea se identifica por un número secuencial dentro del número de red y tiene una determinada longitud. La menor de las líneas posibles abastecerá al menos a dos subestaciones. Una subestación es abastecida sólo por una línea y distribuye a una o varias zonas de servicio. A estos efectos, las provincias (código y nombre), se encuentran divididas en tales zonas de servicio, aunque no puede haber zonas de servicio que pertenezcan a más de una provincia. Cada zona de servicio puede ser atendida por más de una subestación.
>
> En cada zona de servicio se desea registrar el consumo medio y el número de consumidores finales de cada una de las siguientes categorías: particulares, empresas e instituciones

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido Luis, algunos consejillos sin ser yo un maestro: 
1 - entidades = sustantivos, 2 - relaciones = verbos, aunque entiendo que este tema lo tienes machacado, viene bien tenerlo siempre como piedra angular.

Comment: Gracias David! Algo es algo

Comment: Gracias a estas personas que modifican mi post! Soy nuevo aquí y con los nervios y con las prisas escribo peor que un niño de 5 años muerto de frío.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco amplia para el formato del sitio la verdad, normalmente se piden preguntas mucho mas concretas. Yo te recomendaría ir a youtube y buscar "modelos E-R", seguro que hay cientos de tutoriales que te ayudan a comprender los conceptos mejor.

Comment: Como te comenta Pikoh en youtube hay buenos vídeos de E-R, aunque cada uno tiene su forma de hacerlo, otro consejillo que te daría sería ir siempre parte por parte, primero detecta las entidades, sin atributos, siguiente paso, relaciones, esto te ayudará enormemente luego a dibujar el diagrama E-R, y luego los atributos. Pero la respuesta es demasiado amplia y con gustos diferentes según quien sea. Youtube is your friend. Y como mejor se aprende es haciendo ejercicios, ánimo!

Comment: Eso de buscar en YT lo he hecho pero ningún video tiene el nivel que se me exije en el examen. Todos los videos son ejercicios simples que no me sirven de nada insisto, con el nivel que se me pide.

Comment: saludos puedes hallarlo aca: http://mibancodedatos.blogspot.com/

Comment: en el ejercicio 4

Comment: y aca mas detallado: https://es.scribd.com/doc/211281183/Base-de-Datos-3fn

Comment: no quiero la solucion, quiero el proceso, y el scridb ese me viene mejor porque vienen ejercicios que no venían en lo que me dieron